# Lista de validação excel - erro em tempo de execução 1004 - Erro de definição de aplicativo ou de definição de objeto

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

O negócio é assim:
Tenho um vetor que contém os itens para uma lista suspensa no excel. O código logo embaixo cria listas suspensas nas células d5 até d108 em 12 abas do vetor mês. O vetor despesa contém os itens para essa lista suspensa.

Mas na linha indicada dá o seguinte erro:

erro em tempo de execução 1004 - Erro de definição de aplicativo ou de definição de objeto.

```
Dim mes(12) As String
mes(1) = "Janeiro"
mes(2) = "Fevereiro"
mes(3) = "Março"
mes(4) = "Abril"
mes(5) = "Maio"
mes(6) = "Junho"
mes(7) = "Julho"
mes(8) = "Agosto"
mes(9) = "Setembro"
mes(10) = "Outubro"
mes(11) = "Novembro"
mes(12) = "Dezembro"

Dim despesa(19) As String
despesa(1) = "ÁGUA"
despesa(2) = "CONTABILIDADE"
despesa(3) = "DESPESA FIXA"
despesa(4) = "DEVOLUÇÃO"
despesa(5) = "DIARISTA"
despesa(6) = "DIVERSOS"
despesa(7) = "ENERGIA"
despesa(8) = "IPTU"
despesa(9) = "MANUTENÇÃO"
despesa(10) = "MAT. CONSUMO"
despesa(11) = "MAT. CURSOS"
despesa(12) = "MAT. ESCRITÓRIO"
despesa(13) = "MAT. LIMPEZA"
despesa(14) = "MOVIMENTAÇÃO INTERNA"
despesa(15) = "SERVIÇOS GERAIS"
despesa(16) = "SITE"
despesa(17) = "TAXA BANCÁRIA"
despesa(18) = "TEL/INTERNET"
despesa(19) = "VIGILANCIA"

For i = 1 To 12

With Sheets(mes(i)).Range("d5:108").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, 
Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:=Join(despesa, ",") 'erro nesta linha!!!!
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

    Next i
```

O negócio é que até agora não entendi o esquema dos parâmetros e da sintaxe para o método validation. Se alguém puder gastar uns 5 minutos comigo para me dar uma breve explicação eu vou ficar duplamente agradecido!

Qualquer termo que tenha usado de forma errado, eu também vou agradecer qualquer correção educada que puderem fazer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, amigo. Testei exaustivamente seu código e me ora me deparava com o erro, ora não. Levei, bem mais que 5 min, hehehehe...

O erro ocorre quando a inserção de validação está desabilitada, por algum motivo. No meu caso, deparei-me que eu estava com mais de uma worksheet selecionada, porque, antes de rodar o código, eu selecionava todas as planilhas e limpava o conteúdo de todas simultaneamente. Dessa forma o código empacava bem na linha do `Validation.Add`. Contudo, ao pressionar `Depurar`, desativar a múltipla seleção de sheets, e retomar a execução do código, tudo funciona certinho! Imagino, portanto, que vc esteja fazendo algo parecido.

[image: Múltipla Seleção de Planilhas]

[image: Única Seleção de Planilha]

Comment: Cara! Muito obrigado pela atenção! Mas acabei de notar que eu errei na hora de selecionar o range. Faltou o d em "d5:d108"! Foi burrice a minha! xD

Não acredito que eu fiquei 3 horas pra procurar o erro nesse codigo!

Comment: Olá, @HenriqueYujiKamiya. Não entendi! O problema na verdade era com o `Range`? Mas o código não empacava na linha do `.Add`?

Comment: Então! Devem ter sido as duas coisas. O que voce disse faz todo o sentido. QUando várias abas estavam selecionadas, o [validate] não funcionava mesmo.
Resolvendo isso do validate e corrigindo o range, o codigo funcionou.
Mas sim! Quando tinha testado ele, o código empacava no [.add]